# Entry Fields and Text Widths

Tags: python, pygame

I have used a piece of code created by user @skrx which creates a entry field using classes. I have managed to program the code so that when I press enter the screen closes down and returns the content of the entry field to the a variable outside the class.

I thank @skrx for this code, it has helped a lot.

```
class InputBox:
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, text=''):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)
        self.color = COLOR_INACTIVE
        self.text = text
        self.txt_surface = FONT.render(text, True, self.color)
        self.active = False
    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: # If the user clicked on the input_box rect.
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos): # Toggle the active variable.
                self.active = not self.active
            else:
                self.active = False # Change the current color of the input box.
            self.color = COLOR_ACTIVE if self.active else COLOR_INACTIVE
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if self.active:
                if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                    self.text = self.text[:-1]
                else:
                    self.text += event.unicode # Re-render the text.
                self.txt_surface = FONT.render(self.text, True, self.color)
    def update(self): # Resize the box if the text is too long.
        width = max(300, self.txt_surface.get_width()+10)
        self.rect.w = width
    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.txt_surface, (self.rect.x+5, self.rect.y+5)) # Blit the text.
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect, 2)# Blit the rect.
    def ReturnText(self):
        result = self.text
        return result
```

When I press the enter button on the keyboard, the code goes through InputBox.ReturnText() successfully and closes the window. However, the main problem is that the code also returns an error saying:

```
self.txt_surface = FONT.render(self.text, True, self.color)          
pygame.error: Text has zero width
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? (I don't think the problem is with @skrx 's code but is there anything I have to add?)

Answer (score 0):

Simply enough, it looks like Pygame scoffs at `self.text` being empty, thus zero-width.

Add checks for that:

```
def handle_event(...):
    # ...
    if self.text:
        self.txt_surface = FONT.render(self.text, True, self.color)


def draw(...):
    if self.text:
        screen.blit(self.txt_surface, (self.rect.x+5, self.rect.y+5))
    # ...
```

Comment: that sounds about right, but i'm not sure what I can do fix that error.

Comment: See above! Add checks to avoid trying to rerender `txt_surface` or drawing it when there is no text.